# foundation 4 joyride - disable the beginning scroll?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I am having trouble stopping the first scrolling once the page loads. You can see it here http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html . After loading the website, joyride window scrolls automatically page littlebit lower

See it better in the old demo http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

I need the website to load normally (with top bar) and then activate scrolling after "next" button is clicked.

I am using latest version of Foundation 4 and foundation.min

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am trying the docs page and it does not scroll, so either they fixed it or it was not a problem at all initially.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html

Either ways, I see the best solution for you is to have the first step way above in the page, so that even when it takes focus, there's no page scrolling needed.